# Pass data between two Content Page;

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac, .net-maui

I am fairly new to programming in Maui. Previously, I wrote android applications in Xamarin. I have question. How to transfer variables between two Content Page. I try this way:

I have two content page, MainPage and SettingsPage. This is how I send data to SettingsPage:

```
public async void goToSettingsPage_button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(language));
}
```

And this is how I perceive them:

```
public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{
public SettingsPage(string language)
{
    InitializeComponent();
   
    String Language = language;
}
}
```

I just used Intent on xamarin. PutExtra or Intent.GetExtra. I don't know how to work in Maui. How to pass a variable back from SettingsPage to MainPage. I tried to do it in the same way as above;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MessagingCenter` to send the data to the other pages. Also, you can send the data back in the same way.

First, you can send message to the subscriber in the viewmodel of `MyWordPage.Xalm.cs`, just as follows:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, String>(this, "language", English);
}
```

Second, in the viewmodel of `MainPage`, you can subscribe the message and here is the code :

```
public class MainPageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public String mylanguage = "asd" ;
        public String Mylanguage {
            get
            {
                return mylanguage;
            }
            set
            {
                if(mylanguage != value)
                {
                    mylanguage = value;          
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Mylanguage));
                }
            }
        }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, Sring>(this, "language", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Mylanguage = arg;
            });
        }
    }
```

At last,we can bind the `mylanguage` to the label in the `MainPage.xaml` :

```
<Label Text="{Binding mylanguage} "  ></Label>
```

More information you can refer to [Publish and subscribe to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing what you should since you are using NavigationPage for Navigation.

If you check this NavigationPage blog in Maui https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage#pass-data-during-navigation

It shows you how to transfer data.

```
   Contact contact = new Contact
{
    Name = "Jane Doe",
    Age = 30,
    Occupation = "Developer",
    Country = "USA"
};
...
await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(contact));
```

Comment: Ok and how do i sens the data back to MainPage?

Comment: @MichałSchmude, MessagingCenter publish/subscribe.